# Possibility to find a clicked number in a value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to learn, can we find the same number in two input values.
For example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="multinumber" value="1,2,3,4,5">
<input type="hidden" id="justonenumber" value="3">

<div class="click">Click and test the same number</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body").on("click",".click", function(){
    var multiple = $("#multinumber").val();
    var single = $("#justonenumber").val();
  });
});
```

When onClick event on the `.click` button then check the same number in the `#multinumber`  and `#justonenumber` input values and get the result in an alert box.

Is there a way to do this ? Anyone can help me here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `indexOf` or `includes` on your `multiple` string. :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body").on("click",".click", function(){
    var multiple = $("#multinumber").val();
    var single = $("#justonenumber").val();
    var doesMultipleIncludeSingle = multiple.includes(single);
    // OR
    var doesMultipleIncludeSingle = multiple.indexOf(single) > -1;

  });
});
```

As per the problem explained in the comment, it seems the requirement does involve splitting the array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body").on("click",".click", function(){
    var multiple = $("#multinumber").val().split(',');
    var single = $("#justonenumber").val();
    var doesMultipleIncludeSingle = multiple.includes(single);
    // OR
    var doesMultipleIncludeSingle = multiple.indexOf(single) > -1;

  });
});
```

Comment: There is a problem with the finding number. If you change the values like this `<input type="hidden" id="multinumber" value="11,22,33,44,55"> <input type="hidden" id="justonenumber" value="3">` and check the number it is also alert `3` is found but there is not have uniq number `3`.

Comment: I see.. In that case you need to split the `multiple` value. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body").on("click",".click", function(){
    var multiple = $("#multinumber").val();
    var single = $("#justonenumber").val();
    if(multiple.indexOf(single) > -1) alert(single + " is found");
    else alert(single + " isn't found");
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you really need to `.split`? ;)

Comment: removed.. thnx @AdityaParab

Comment: @mshouman There is a problem with the finding number. If you change the values like this `<input type="hidden" id="multinumber" value="11,22,33,44,55">
<input type="hidden" id="justonenumber" value="3">` and check the number it is also alert 3 is found but there is not have uniq number 3.

Comment: @Azzo I wrote it with splitting it to array but I have changed it so now it's necessary to split the multinumber

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of first input box.  Split it by `,` and check with `.indexOf` for the other input. If it's there, you can put the result in alert box like

```js
$(".click").click(function(){

  var x = $("#multinumber").val().split(",");
  var y = $("#justonenumber").val();
  
  if(x.indexOf(y) > 0){
   alert(x.find(o=> o==y))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="multinumber" value="1,2,3,4,5">
<input type="hidden" id="justonenumber" value="3">

<div class="click">Click and test the same number</div>
```

Comment: Do you really need `.split`? ;)

Comment: Ah! Not really. it can be skipped. 
Thanks for pointing though :)